# Firefox 36 aborts https requests with content length greater than 1778

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, firefox, tomcat

1. With Firefox 36 version ajax POST requests (via jquery) are getting aborted (in firebug status is aborted) if the content length is >= 1779. If the size is <= 1778 requests are sent to server
2. Same requests are working fine in Chrome and Firefox 35 or less for any content-length.
3. Server Environment: Apache Http forwards to Tomcat 7.

Question:

1. Is any settings in Firefox 36 that aborts posting data if content length is >= 1779 ?
2. Is any configuration available in Apache Http Server or Apache Tomcat to DOS for requests from specific browser version and content-length ? (Is aborted in Firefox means DOS from server ?)

Thanks,
-Barath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is fixed after following the steps mentioned in this [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1050465#answer-701318)

Answer (score 0):

I can answer part 2. There is nothing in Tomcat or httpd that is specific to the combination of user agent and content length.

What is possible is that Firefox 36 has changed the details of how it is sending the request and that is - somehow - tripping over a default limit. I'd recommend using Firebug or similar to look at the HTTP request and response in detail - in particular how they vary between FireFox 36 and earlier versions.

Comment: This issue is fixed by following the steps mention in the [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1050465#answer-701318)